# update existing JSON property value based on MongoDB Results in NodeJS

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, mongodb

i have a JSON like below

```
            var outputJson = [
                {
                    'Product' : 'TV',
                    'isSelected': 0
                },
                {
                    'Product' : 'Radio',
                    'isSelected': 0
                },
                {
                    'Product' : 'Book',
                    'isSelected': 0
                },                      
                {
                    'Product' : 'Watch',
                    'isSelected': 0
                }                 
            ]
```

Now my goal is to find if user has any of this products in MongoDB, if yes than i want to update isSelected value from "0" to "1". How do i do that, below is what i am trying to do but my JSON Is not updating

> ```
>             outputJson.forEach(function(key,value){
>                 wishlistData.find({userID:req.user.id}, function(err,data{
>                     data.forEach(function(k,i){
>                         if (data[i].product=== outputJson[value].Product){
>                             outputJson[value].isSelected = 1
>                         }
>                     })
>                 }); 
>             });
> ```

Comment: Use $in to select users and $inc to update params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using Promise my issue got resolved

```
Promise.all(outputJson.map(function(i,k) {
  return wishlistData.findOne({userID: req.user.id, product: i.Product}).then(function(data, err) {
    if (data !== null) { // if it actually found a match
      i.isSelected = 1;
    }
  });
})).then(function() {
    console.log(outputJson);
});
```